# Preserving argument spacing, etc when passing into mvn exec:java

Tags: bash, maven-2, shell, arguments

I have a shell script that launches a Maven exec:java process -

```
exec mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=... -Dexec.args="$*"
```

Now sadly if I run

```
./myMagicShellScript arg1 "arg 2"
```

the single string `arg 2` doesn't make it through as a single argument as I'd like.

Any thoughts as to how to escape / pass things through properly (perferably in a clean way)?

Comment: I share your pain. So many level of escaping and tokenization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at the [`mvn` script](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/maven-2/branches/maven-2.2.x/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn?view=markup) and did some testing. This is what I came up with:

Try changing your script to look like this:

```
args=(${@// /\\ })
exec mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=... -Dexec.args="${args[*]}"
```

That changes all spaces which are within each array element to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: When I do that, Maven tries to interpret the rest of the command line instead of passing it in as exec.args :(

Comment: What does it do if you pass it explicit arguments: `...-Dexec.args="arg1 'arg 2'"`? Are the single quotes included in the value? If so is that desirable? What about `...-Dexec.args="arg1 arg\ 2"`?

Comment: Wow, this is awful.  a 'b c' -> "a", "'b", "c'".  a b\ c seems to work though.

Comment: @Steven: is `mvn` a script or a binary?

Comment: It's a shell script that does this strange magic:

QUOTED_ARGS=""
while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do

  QUOTED_ARGS="$QUOTED_ARGS \"$1\""
  shift

done

Comment: Yup, like a charm.  I can't help but worry that it will fail disastrously in the most important time when encountering particularly strange characters coming in, but so far it handled the admittedly cursory testing admirably.

Comment: Almost worked for me: I had to quote the args in QUOTED_ARGS with single-quote characters, not double quotes. Otherwise, I just got an 'Unable to parse command line' error from mvn