# Run a command line with an option as an arguments

Tags: java, bash, maven

I want to run an instruction using bash with some arguments. Among these arguments I have 
`"-- stat"`. So when I run my instruction, the bash recognize the `"--stat"` as an option of Mavan and not an arguments.

Example of my instruction :

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MainClass" -Dexec.args="args1 --stat args3 ..."
```

and when I run this command line I have this error :

```
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --stat
```

What can I do to run this command line with `"--stat"` arguments ?

Comment: What maven version are you using?

Comment: `Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-1)`

Comment: Are you sure it is Maven complaining and not your `MainClass`?

Comment: I dont understand your question. It my mainClass to run my program with arguments given in `-Dexec.args`.
When i make an instruction directly on bash its work but when i write it on file.bash and i run my bash file i cannot because `--stat` is used by mvn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check whether this is useful.

[Preserving argument spacing, etc when passing into mvn exec:java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570377/preserving-argument-spacing-etc-when-passing-into-mvn-execjava)

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=... -Dexec.args="${args[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, command is assuming --stat as argument to mvn, rather than to child program. See if this helps:

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MainClass" -Dexec.args="args1 -- --stat args3 ..."
```

Generally -- is used for escaping any following -option or --option. This *MAY* work for you.

Comment: I have  : `[INFO] Invalid task '--stat': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal`

Comment: I got confused because of 'Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --stat' error.

Comment: Just a stupid question: looking at "lifecycle phase, or a goal", I just hope, it's not a typo from --start to --stat :D